# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3c in Backoffice, Hybris 2011

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I keep getting this error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3c while trying to update the CMS Banner text through Hybris Backoffice, there was hybris platform update from 1811 to 2011, after that we are getting this issue.

Can there be any suggestions?

```
ERROR [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8010-exec-10] [10.16.98.142] [UiEngineImpl]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/11/24 07:02:58.913 | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 26
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/11/24 07:02:58.913 |         at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:746) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/11/24 07:02:58.913 |         at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:538) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/11/24 07:02:58.913 |         at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:561) ~[?:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/11/24 07:02:58.913 |         at com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.wysiwyg.WysiwygEditor.onChangeEvent(WysiwygEditor.java:165) ~[cockpit-standard-editors-20.11.5-RC5.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/11/24 07:02:58.913 |         at com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.wysiwyg.WysiwygEditor.lambda$render$1(WysiwygEditor.java:94) ~[cockpit-standard-editors-20.11.5-RC5.jar:?]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/11/24 07:02:58.913 |         at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:3179) ~[zk-8.6.3.jar:8.6.3]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/11/24 07:02:58.913 |         at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:3149) ~[zk-8.6.3.jar:8.6.3]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/11/24 07:02:58.913 |         at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:3091) ~[zk-8.6.3.jar:8.6.3]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/11/24 07:02:58.913 |         at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:138) ~[zk-8.6.3.jar:8.6.3]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/11/24 07:02:58.913 |         at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1845) ~[zk-8.6.3.jar:8.6.3]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/11/24 07:02:58.913 |         at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1617) [zk-8.6.3.jar:8.6.3]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/11/24 07:02:58.913 |         at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execUpdate(UiEngineImpl.java:1320)
```

Comment: Your error message mentions 26 (which would be `&`) and your text mentions 3c (which would be `<`). Both of those are not part of any widely-used Base64 variant. So the most likely thing is something is not sending Base64 encoded data, when it's supposed to.

Comment: Yes check the text, maybe you'll see something like `&#10;` - an XML entity for a LineFeed; Base64 sometimes uses line breaks (a variant). It could also be a query string like: `base64&other=...`.